# Как привести настоящее время JS к конкретному формату (June 6, 2019, с указанием времени)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, дата

С переменной формата this.date = 'June 6, 2019' все работает, но мне нужно именно конкретное время + 15 минут. Типа `Date.now()` (прибавив 15 минут), которое потом обрабатывать, но меняя строковое значение, например, на `new Date().toDateString()` я получаю на выходе набор NaN'ов. Как это выправить?

Comment: какой-то сумбур... изложите проблему без лишней "воды". При чем тут код, который Вы привели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно что вы хотите.

Если вам нужно получить значение `Date` увеличенное на `n` минут от текущего времени, то делается это так:

```js
new Date(Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000) // n = 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял вопроса, что в итоге должно быть, но я реализовывал для себя утилитку, которая делает из строки дату, а из даты строку. Выглядит вот так

```
class DateUtil {
  constructor() { }

  convertStrToDate(datestring) {  // конвертация строки типа "25.03.2019 12:26:43" в формат Date
    return new Date(datestring.replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/, '$3-$2-$1T$4:$5:$6.000Z'));
  }

  dateToStr(date) {  // конвертация Date() в строку типа "25.03.2019 12:26"
    const hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
    const mins = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
    const mm = ((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10) ? '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1);
    const dd = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
    return `${date.getFullYear()}.${mm}.${dd} ${hours}:${mins}`;
  }
}
```